# TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, pinchzoom

I'm trying to use [PinchZoomer](http://codecanyon.net/item/pinch-zoomer-jquery-plugin/6623080), a Jquery plugin on a Wordpress Website but I get this error twice in firebug: TypeError: $ is not a function

I know I should use "jQuery" instead of the $ sign in Wordpress but it doesn't make a difference in this case. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
        $(".pinchzoom").pinchzoomer();
});
</script>
```

And here's my code to enqueue jQuery and the PinchZoomer plugin in Wordpress:

```
function add_jQuery_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('hammer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pinchzoomer/jquery.hammer.min.js', array() );
    wp_enqueue_script('mousewheel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pinchzoomer/jquery.mousewheel.min.js', array() );
    wp_enqueue_script('pinchzoomer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pinchzoomer/jquery.pinchzoomer.min.js', array() );
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pinchzoomer/modernizr.min.js', array() );
    wp_enqueue_script('tweenmax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pinchzoomer/TweenMax.min.js', array() );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jQuery_scripts');
```

[This is the page](http://dev.chezbrutus.com/barbrutus/menu/) where pinchzoomer should work.

What am I missing?

Comment: The jQuery library is not being loaded correctly for some reason, or is not loaded at the point you attempt to use it.

Comment: Isn't jQuery normally included with wordpress? I though all you have to do is something like `wp_enqueue_script( 'tweenmax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pinchzoomer/TweenMax.min.js', array('jquery'));`

Comment: Actually yeah I'm pretty sure all you have to do is add jQuery to that array as that it declaring the dependencies for that file.

Comment: Make sure jQuery isn't running in no-conflict mode. if it is, the `$` shorthand can't be used, and you need to call jQuery like this : `jQuery(selector)` rather than `$(selector)`

Comment: Are you saying your code throws an error on `$` but does not on `jQuery`? What if you use `jQuery` in place of `$`? Do you still get an error?

Comment: If you go to the page you referenced and evaluate `$` it is undefined.

Comment: What if you remove the callback parameter, `$` should already be defined and you shouldn't have to pass it through.

Comment: The plugin is now working but I still get aTypeError. But this time looks like it's on the pinchzoomer plugin... I'm using this code to call pinchzoomer: <script type="text/javascript">
$=jQuery;

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".pinchzoom").pinchzoomer();
});
 
</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The initial problem

According to the [Wordpress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for wp_enqueue_script, in the third parameter are the dependencies for that file.

This parameter is optional and accepts a type of array. So that jQuery can be used for that file all you would need to do is add it to as a dependency.

For example:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'tweenmax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/pinchzoomer/TweenMax.min.js', array('jquery'));
```

You can read more about this [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery) where the docs explain about 'Linking a Theme Script Which Depends on jQuery'.

### Possibly redundant code

I don't think you need to have this part in your code as I think that Wordpress comes with jQuery and you would be defining it as a dependency while 'enqueue-ing' the relevant scripts :

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

### No Conflict Mode

Finally, for the comment about putting jQuery in no conflict and having the dollar symbol present in the function.

By having the dollar symbol in the brackets next to function, this is basically just introducing the `$` symbol to the local scope as a way of accessing jQuery without having to re-type jQuery every time while in 'no conflict' mode.

i.e. It's just a shorter way of accessing it. You can read about no conflict wrappers in Wordpress and about using `$` for short [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) in the docs.

Therefore using the library in the following way should be fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".pinchzoom").pinchzoomer();
});
```

### Problems with PinchZoomer

From looking at the plugins source code and as we discussed in the comments, it could possibly be a problem with the PinchZoomer plugin itself on line 1440 as they have not themselves made `$` available to their local scope.

You can test this by setting a breakpoint online 1440, refreshing the page and setting the value of `$` to `jQuery`. If you have access to the source code your self you could make the fix, although really they should make the fix themselves.

The broken code on lines 1433 - 1442 should be fixed to look like the following code:

```
(function($)
{
    function onReady()
    {
        PinchZoomer.init();
    }

    $(onReady);

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Ok I see thanks for the tip...I'm now using array('jquery') for every enqueue script

Comment: @Dali I have edited my answer to include the problems with PinchZoomer, the includes how you could fix it yourself if you have access to the code.

Answer (score 1):

When I go to the page you referenced if I evaluate `$` in the console I get undefined, but `jQuery` is defined. I think your issue may be the callback variable, if `jQuery` is defined than you shouldn't have to worry about `$` being defined unless there is a library conflict.

This should work:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".pinchzoom").pinchzoomer();
});
```

Here is a short-hand version of what you are doing:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $(".pinchzoom").pinchzoomer();
});
// Or
$(function() {
    $(".pinchzoom").pinchzoomer();
});
```

### As an Anonymous Function

Another alternative would be to wrap your jquery within an anonymous function:

```
(function($) {
    // All of your jquery calls inside of here
    $(function() {
        $(".pinchzoom").pinchzoomer();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Using the $ is a way that Wordpress themselves suggest as it is just a way of introducing $ into the local scope as a shorthand way of accessing jQuery.

Comment: @Dan I would love to see that suggestion by the Wordpress team, not arguing, just curious. In my experience and research I've found more people using the Anonymous function approach and/or using no conflict, such as `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`. I actually hadn't seen using `$` as a callback param before.

Comment: @JonathanJones the comment was made prior to Asok adding the anonymous function part, I am actually for using the anonymous function approach in the correct situations... I guess my comment now looks out of context with Asoks changes. Prior to my comment, his answer was essentially just saying that removing the $ from the params would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code before ready function.

```
$=jQuery;
```

Also please use $ or jQuery in second line you use $ please use jQuery and check.

Comment: By defining the $ in the parameters of the jQuery function, it is making jQuery available to the local scope. This is a standard way of having jQuery in a 'no conflict mode' whilst at the same time introducing $ to the local scope as a shorthand for accessing jQuery.

Comment: Ok it's working! But there is still an error: TypeError: $ is not a function
$(onReady);

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$=jQuery;

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".pinchzoom").pinchzoomer();
});
 
</script>

Comment: Have just had a look and it seems to be a problem with the plugin your using. Doing `$=jQuery` would be a bad way of doing things. At the bottom of the pinchzoomer file, there is this code which is causing the problem `(function()
{
 function onReady()
 {
  PinchZoomer.init();
 }
 
 $(onReady);
 
}());`

Comment: Oh ok...so I should go to plugin support...Thks for your help